# Which API/approach to use to grant external app access to a single SharePoint online folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

Here's what I am trying to achieve. I have a client that is not technical (meaning I cannot ask them to ever load PowerShell and I will not be doing it for them a year down the line etc.) that need me to write some code for an external system to upload files into a dedicated SharePoint folder. They do not want an app that grants full site access - just a single folder.

I first looked at the SharePoint apps but A) they seem to be deprecated soon, B) do not grant fine grain access and C) are a nightmare for non tech to renew secrets.

I then explore Azure app and I see that I can renew secret there without PowerShell and there is something called Sites.Selected which even after searching is a bit vague on how to use. I may be going in wrong direction.

I am not sure this is possible but I see a lot of talk around it.

Suggestion? I ideally want something that doesn't need to have a secret to renew or at least a basic process that client can follow.

Answer (score 0):

There are no permission scopes that grant access to a single folder.

When using the Add-in permission model, that is when registering an app with Azure Access Control Services (ACS) via `appregnew.aspx`, the most granular permission scope grants access to a list or library. However, as you've mentioned, Microsoft has stated that Add-ins and the Add-in permission model will be deprecated at some point in the future.

When registering an app with Entra ID (Azure AD), the most granular permission scope grants access to a site collection. That's the `Sites.Selected` scope you mentioned in your question. I know that the community, myself included, has made requests to the product team for more granular permission scopes but I have not seen any public statements that indicate if or when we will get them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Perhaps I will further explore the Sites.Selected. There is a bit of a lack of docs on how to assign the selected sites. Some docs say to use powershell but if I try to auth the app using a browser URL it tells me "Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user. The specific site collections and the permissions granted will be configured in SharePoint Online." But I cannot find any trace of it. Do you know where this is managed in the SP dashboard?